# Migrate from swift 2.2 to swift 3.0 in xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

How to migrate from **swift 2.2** to **swift 3.0** on **Xcode 8.0**.

Do i need to update all the **3rd party libraries** also ?

Please help !!!

Comment: Yes, to this day (it will change with Swift 4) your libraries have to be made with the same Swift version as your app. Be aware that many of them are not ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 2.2 unfortunately doesn't work with Xcode 8. But Apple made a good move still supporting Swift 2.3, which is basically almost the same as 2.2.

The problem is with 3rd party libraries, which must be in the same version of Swift as your project.

So, if you're using Swift 2.3, you can't use libraries, that are written in Swift 3.0.